# LINQ to filter properties by custom attributes

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, custom-attributes

I am using EF code-first and I have put a custom attribute on some of the fields in a model, which I want to exclude(like, I dont want to send the Id attribute value to client side).
Now, I need to return only the columns which doesn't have the attribute.
Right now, I am thinking to do it in 2 steps: Get all the data then filter by the attribute.

But I know, this can be done in a single query.
Please help.

Comment: What about `NotMappedAttribute` which already exists and supported by EF?

Comment: Actually, this functionality is needed only for one feature, not always.

Comment: then I'd think about separate entity for that feature instead of adding and handling custom attribute for entity which is used everywhere

Comment: Yes. Actually, I was looking for any stylish way to achieve this.